# Component requesting data after sorting

Tags: reactjs, components, axios

I have table which consists of two rows, in one there is data and in the other there is a component which is a smaller table. The component recive props and make a get request to API. 
The problem apered when I add a sort function to a big table. After sorting the small table which is component reload and always send a new request to API.

I've made a small table similar to mine to show the problem.

https://codesandbox.io/s/olm0qmly6q

If you sort a Table, the component is reloading and axios make a new get request

How could I somehow store data to limit request to API?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to change `componentWillReceiveProps` function in `Table` component to `componentDidUpdate` and add checking that `name` prop has been changed (or `id` prop, but you don't pass this props to `Table` component).
2. You have to add `key` property to the fragment that you return from `data.map(user => {...})`.

Here you can see the result:
https://codesandbox.io/s/2vw54pm780

Comment: Thanks! `<React.Fragment key={id}>` solved the problem !